# Could not find or load main class ScalaProject

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jar

i created a scala spark project on intellij and created the executable jar file. However when i open up the command prompt, go to the jar file location and enter

```
java -jar ScalaProject.jar
```

It throws an error saying:

```
Error: cound not find or load main class SparkProject
```

I have tried removing my main method and extending APP like so

```
object SparkProject extends APP { 

}
```

but it still shows the errors. Any ideas??

Comment: 1. `SparkProjec` 2. `SparkProject`.

Comment: How do you create your jar? Perhaps a helpful link: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_building.html#building